# Generate single JSON array from several input objects using jq

Tags: arrays, json, jq

I do have several similar JSON objects (e.g. in files):

```
file_1.json: {"myArray":[{a},{b}]}
...
file_n.json: {"myArray":[{n},{m}]}
```

I would like to transform all these files into one output with the following format, using jq and Linux or Windows command line tools:

```
result_file.json: [{a},{b},...,{n},{m}]
```

So, I just want one array having all the objects that can be found in the "myArray" arrays from the different inputs.

Currently I use this command, which separates the objects, but doesn't create an array that includes them:

```
type file_1.json file_n.json | jq ".result[]" > result_file.json
```

(replace type with cat on Linux)

How can I get the format right?

Answer (score 6):

You can "slurp" your inputs:

> -s        read (slurp) all inputs into an array; apply filter to it;

(man jq)

Like that:

1.json

```
{"myArray":[1,2,3]}
```

2.json

```
{"myArray":[3,4,5]}
```

`%jq -s '[.[].myArray[]]' 1.json 2.json`

```
[
  1,
  2,
  3,
  3,
  4,
  5
]
```